# Calculating voronoi sites with a 2D grid

Tags: 2d, mathematics, procedural-generation, grid

I've been diving deeper into voronoi cells for use in a 2D game. There's a lot out there that explains the concept and describes how to calculate them but I'm failing to grasp how best to apply them to a 2D grid.

Mainly, in order to calculate the voronoi cells/edges you need a list of points ("sites").

Do I just choose random points on my grid? If so I need to ensure they're chosen in the right order due to my RNG seed. That doesn't sound reasonable for the world as a whole, so maybe I can use a new seed for every "chunk".

Any advice or further explanation would be great. I have an idea, and lots of example logic on calculating the cells/edges, it's just the points in relation to an infinite 2d grid I have trouble with.

Comment: Choosing a random point in each cell of a grid (sometimes called a "shaken" or "jittered" grid) is indeed one way Voronoi points are often selected. You can use a hash of the chunk's location or ID to seed the generation - hash algorithms are generally better at decorrelating outcomes in "breadth" (many items seeded independently) while PRNG algorithms are optimized for "depth" (many items generated sequentially off of one seed). So right now the answer to your question is basically "yes, if you want to do it that way" - are there particular issues with that approach you're trying to fix?

Comment: I haven't tried to implement anything yet as I'm just trying to understand how it will work. As mentioned my world uses chunks and each one holds 3x3 tiles. In each chunk I should hash the coords, use that as a new seed for the rng, choose X random points (how many? a 3x3 chunk isn't very large) and then compare that to it's neighbor chunks? Once I have the list of neighbor sites I can calculate the edges/cells. If that sounds right, I believe I can try it.

Comment: You don't need our assent or approval to dive in and try an approach that sounds good to you. ;)

Comment: Sure but I also hoped for input from people who have done this/more familiarity with voronoi, I'd rather not spend time uf I have a fundamentally flawed understanding.

Comment: What do you want to do with the voronoi cells? It's difficult to recommend a site generation technique without knowing your intent &/or constraints.

Comment: They'd be useful for many reasons, but for the moment I'm thinking of using them for roads. I'd like to have some paths leading around my world and using the cell edges would work well. Folks have also suggested I use the cells for plant/decor placement.